# Split sublist of a list into other sublists

Tags: python, list

I am having problems with 'splitting' a larger list into several of it's combinations. Here is an example:

Let's say I have this list:

```
  x = [['a','b'],['c','f'],['q','w','t']]
```

and I want to end up with

```
  x = [['a','b'],['c','f'],['q','w'],['q','t'],['w','t']]
```

so essentially

```
 ['q','w','t']
```

becomes

```
 ['q','w'],['q','t'],['w','t']
```

I see how I can convert

```
 ['q','w','t']
```

to

```
 [['q','w'],['q','t'],['w','t']] #notice the extra brackets
```

with itertools combinations, but then I am stuck with

```
 x = [['a','b'],['c','f'],[['q','w'],['q','t'],['w','t']]] #notice the extra brackets
```

Which is not what I want.

How should I do this?

EDIT:

Here is the "solution", that does not give me the result that I want:

```
from itertools import combinations

x = [['a','b'],['c','f'],['q','w','t']]

new_x = []

for sublist in x:
    if len(sublist) == 2:
        new_x.append(sublist)
    if len(sublist) > 2:
        new_x.append([list(ele) for ele in (combinations(sublist,2))])
```

Thank You

Comment: You just need to change the second `append(...)` to `extend(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I generally use a nested list comprehension to flatten a list like this:

```
>>> x = [['a','b'],['c','f'],['q','w','t']]
>>> [c for s in x for c in itertools.combinations(s, 2)]
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'f'), ('q', 'w'), ('q', 't'), ('w', 't')]
```

Comment: This does what I want! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 2):

Not the best way to do it but pretty clear for understanding:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [['a','b'],['c','f'],['q','w','t']]

def get_new_list(x):

    newList = []
    for l in x:
        if len(l) > 2:
            newList.extend([list(sl) for sl  in combinations(l, 2)])
        else:
            newList.append(l)
    return newList

print get_new_list(a)
>>> [['a','b'],['c','f'],['q','w'],['q','t'],['w','t']]
```